# ntp server reachable but never select/set the time

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

We have some embedded devices using ntpd(4.2.8p10) to sync the time. One of our customers is using their own ntp server inside an internal network. From the ntpd -dgq  debug mode, we found the server is reachable and we can get the offset, delay and jitter info. However, the ntpd will only exit with"**ntpd: no servers found**" and never select and set the local time.

```
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Thu Jul 26 19:52:20 UTC 2018 (2): Starting
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Command line: ntpd -dgq
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: proto: precision = 2.000 usec (-19)
Finished Parsing!!
restrict: op 1 addr 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 mflags 00000000 flags 000005f0
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00000000 flags 00000000
restrict source template mflags 4000 flags 1c0
restrict: op 1 addr (null) mask (null) mflags 00004000 flags 000001c0
move_fd: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1:123
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Listen normally on 2 eth1 192.168.168.109:123
restrict: op 1 addr 192.168.168.109 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Listen normally on 3 wlan0 192.168.100.1:123
restrict: op 1 addr 192.168.100.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001
2 Nov 11:57:05 ntpd[20218]: Listening on routing socket on fd #27 for interface updates
key_expire: at 0 associd 60163
peer_clear: at 0 next 1 associd 60163 refid INIT
restrict: op 1 addr 10.160.129.161 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00004000 flags 000001c0
restrict_source: 10.160.129.161 host restriction added
event at 0 10.160.129.161 8011 81 mobilize assoc 60163
newpeer: 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x101 0x1 ttl 0 key 00000000
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
peer_xmit: at 1 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 len 48 xmt 0xe52bde52.ddf3c87c
auth_agekeys: at 1 keys 0 expired 0
event at 1 10.160.129.161 8014 84 reachable
clock_filter: n 1 off 30.082946 del 0.048598 dsp 7.945314 jit 0.000002
peer_xmit: at 3 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 len 48 xmt 0xe52bde54.ddf0a416
clock_filter: n 2 off 30.083616 del 0.047583 dsp 3.949228 jit 0.000670
peer_xmit: at 5 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 len 48 xmt 0xe52bde56.dde968ab
clock_filter: n 3 off 30.078398 del 0.054469 dsp 1.951189 jit 0.004895
peer_xmit: at 7 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 len 48 xmt 0xe52bde58.dde80026
clock_filter: n 4 off 30.079499 del 0.074539 dsp 0.952172 jit 0.003164
peer_xmit: at 9 192.168.168.109->10.160.129.161 mode 3 len 48 xmt 0xe52bde5a.ddea03c8
clock_filter: n 5 off 30.083616 del 0.044472 dsp 0.452664 jit 0.003340
2 Nov 11:57:16 ntpd[20218]: ntpd: no servers found
END OF FILE
```

Also, when running ntpd in the background and using **ntpq -p** to query the ntpd status.
We get the following result, the st, delay, offset and reach seem fine.

```
root@S8P20092901:~# ntpq -c as

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 59609  9014   yes   yes  none    reject   reachable  1

root@S8P20092901:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay    offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 10.160.129.161  162.159.200.123  4 u  24   64   377    40.404    -180.122   20.122
```

However, the ntpd never select the ntp server as the time source(never show "*" or "+" before the remote address ) or sets the local time after a long time of waiting.

I looked into the source code. When using ntpdate(-q) mode the ntpd will exit after doing all bursts for every server when there is no clock selected/ set

```
    } else {
        peer->burst--;
        if (peer->burst == 0) {

            /*
             * If ntpdate mode and the clock has not been
             * set and all peers have completed the burst,
             * we declare a successful failure.
             */
            if (mode_ntpdate) {
                peer_ntpdate--;
                if (peer_ntpdate == 0) {
                    msyslog(LOG_NOTICE,
                        "ntpd: no servers found");
                    if (!msyslog_term)
                        printf(
                            "ntpd: no servers found\n");
                    exit (0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am still not understand why ntpd didn't select and set a time form the server. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for your suggestion. I just replaced the image with text

Comment: Without showing the config file, it's hard to answer the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be a root dispersion issue (the cumulative error from the time source to your server).

You've provided `ntpq -nc associations` already:

> ```
> ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
> ===========================================================
>   1 ​59609  9014   yes   yes  none    reject   reachable  1
> ```

so now what's required is to show the detail for this problematic association:

```
ntpq -nc 'readvar 59609'
```

You should get something like this (taken from my own NTP server)

```
associd=33428 status=142a reach, sel_candidate, 2 events, sys_peer,
srcadr=90.255.244.219, srcport=123, dstadr=192.168.1.18, dstport=123,
leap=00, stratum=1, precision=-20, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=1.511,
refid=PPS, reftime=e53ca0fb.4d946a30  Mon, Nov 15 2021  9:03:55.303,
rec=e53ca11e.bf1413cd  Mon, Nov 15 2021  9:04:30.746, reach=377,
unreach=0, hmode=3, pmode=4, hpoll=10, ppoll=10, headway=0, flash=00 ok,
keyid=0, offset=-0.249, delay=22.177, dispersion=55.975, jitter=56.489,
xleave=0.088,
filtdelay=   157.46  161.45  169.05   22.18   21.68   21.76  186.40   22.04,
filtoffset=   70.21   70.72   74.51   -0.25   -0.03   -0.26   81.90   -0.34,
filtdisp=      0.00   15.39   31.02   47.04   63.23   79.22   86.97   94.76
```

Look for the `rootdisp` value. I expect you'll find that yours is high, indicating that there's too much error in the path from the time source to here. There's not a lot you can do about that except use a different upstream server. (You could fix up `maxdisp` but you have to ask how reliable your upstream server really is, if you have to do this.)

References:

- Cisco - [Troubleshoot ISE and NTP Server Synchronization Failures on Microsoft Windows](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/identity-services-engine/119371-technote-ise-00.pdf) (PDF)
- NTP - [reference documentation for `ntpq`](https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/ntpq.html)
- ServerFault - [Why is NTP considering my server inadequate?](https://serverfault.com/q/886954/267016)

Comment: Thanks for your information. However, when I waited for a couple of minutes. The ntpd is still not syncing with the server(which didn't show * or + in the front). And the reach already goes to 377.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. You are right. The rootdisp is really high for our customer ntp server. We have to add "tos maxdist 30"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem which started with [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686714/automatic-time-synchronization-ntpdate-works-but-chrony-does-not).

The solution was indeed to add the `tos maxdist 30` to `/etc/ntp.conf` and below I list all the steps for checking and solving it. Do note that this should only be performed in case there is no option for another time server: as stated by others, it also means that the upstream NTP server is not really reliable.

Here are the steps:

If you use `ntpd -dgq`, you might get an `unable to bind to wildcard address`  error. Hence, before running it, you need to stop the NTP service `service ntp stop` or kill the processes holding the NTP:

```
lsof -i | grep ntp
kill <pid>
```

After that, run the `ntpd -dgq` command. If you get this final part of the log, then the NTP server is unreachable:

```
...
...
...
receive: MATCH_ASSOC dispatch: mode 4/server:AM_PROCPKT
filegen  2 3854076120
clock_filter: n 5 off 3.839496 del 0.000455 dsp 0.437525 jit 0.000248
17 Feb 09:42:02 ntpd[1040]: ntpd: no servers found
```

Also, after restarting the NTP service (`service ntp start`), the same thing can be visible with commands below - server is reachable but the time sync cannot be performed:

```
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -c as
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 34463  9014   yes   yes  none    reject   reachable  1
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   36   64    7    0.579  3917.57   5.842
```

As stated, the reason is a large `rootdisp` value of the output below (use `assid` from `ntpq -c as` as input `readvar`):

```
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -nc 'readvar 34463'
associd=34463 status=9014 conf, reach, sel_reject, 1 event, reachable,
srcadr=172.16.0.25, srcport=123, dstadr=172.16.0.133, dstport=123,
leap=00, stratum=1, precision=-23, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=10684.280,
refid=LOCL, reftime=e5b7a483.b4d87c2d  Wed, Feb 16 2022 17:27:47.706,
rec=e5b88b72.a5c64a66  Thu, Feb 17 2022  9:53:06.647, reach=377,
unreach=0, hmode=3, pmode=4, hpoll=6, ppoll=6, headway=290,
flash=400 peer_dist, keyid=0, offset=3934.131, delay=0.516,
dispersion=0.987, jitter=14.653, xleave=0.037,
filtdelay=     0.52    0.52    0.56    0.54    0.54    0.58    0.45    0.49,
filtoffset= 3934.13 3930.84 3927.44 3924.11 3920.90 3917.58 3914.35 3911.63,
filtdisp=      0.00    1.02    2.06    3.08    4.10    5.12    6.11    6.95
```

Finally, these are the commands to add `tos maxdist 30` to `/etc/ntp.conf` and restart the NTP service:

```
echo 'tos maxdist 30' >> /etc/ntp.conf
service ntp restart
```

And, voilà - time is sucessfuly synchronized with your NTP server:

```
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -c as
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 60446  961a   yes   yes  none  sys.peer    sys_peer  1
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   15   64    1    0.432    0.314   0.171
```

Comment: This is a very nicely presented answer